# Nested Stack Navigator resetting to initialRoute after app is closed and reopened in Android (without swipe)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a nested Stack Navigators like this (names are changed). If I go from the InitialStack to the HomeStack and from then to any of the screens in HomeStack or the other stacks, when I close the app (without swipe) it automatically resets to the first screen of the InitialStack

```
const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
        {
                InitialStack: InitialStack,
                HomeStack: HomeStack,
                StackC: StackC,
                StackD: StackD,
        },
        {
                initialRouteName: 'InitialStack',
                defaultNavigationOptions: {
                        header: null
                },
        }
)

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootStack);
```

I want to keep the current screen being rendered instead of the initial one from the initialStack after the apps has been reopened.

I am using react-navigation 4.0.10 and react-native 0.61.2

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method [componentwillunmount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillunmount)

It is activated as soon as you close the component

Then you can use [asyncStorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage#setitem) "setitem"

This is how you save the page you were on

After the component is restarted

You will get the figure of the last open component with this method asyncStorage getitem

And open it up with this method  [componentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)